# How to convert EPS to mathtype (.mml) using command line

Tags: mathml, mathtype

I am having an `.eps` equation file which is created using mathtype

now I want to convert that `.eps` to `.mml` or any markup language format using only command line tool

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to directly save an EPS as MathML, whether using the command line or some other method. It requires parsing the contents of the EPS, looking for some things that MathType always includes in its EPSs.

At the top of any EPS created by MathType is a group of comments. At the very end of those comments is the MathML. The beginning of the string of MathML is this:

`<?xmlversion="1.0"?><!--MathType@Translator@5@5@MathML2(Clipboard).tdl@MathML2.0(Clipboard)@-->`

At the end is this: `<!--MathType@End@5@5@-->!`. Everything between these is MathML.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information ! Bob, I will try with this and let you know